# what is the prolem in my code? it not compiled and get error.Please help me

Tags: java

This is the program for print the character of given index.But is gets error in function.
I give the function return type as char.But compiler told to rename the return type of main function

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Demo5{
    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner n=new Scanner(System.in);
        String p=n.next();
        int q=n.nextInt();
        System.out.println(showchar(p,q));
        
        public char showchar(String s,int num)
        {
        
            char c=s.charAt(num);
            return c;
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: You are defining a method inside another method, that is not valid java syntax. The `showchar` method needs to be out side of your main method.

Comment: Spiders is right, but in the future make sure to read the actual compiler error message and include it in the question when posting here. Error messages are a very useful diagnostic tool.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner n=new Scanner(System.in);
        String p=n.next();
        int q=n.nextInt();
        System.out.println(showchar(p,q));
    }
 public static char showchar(String s,int num)
    {
        char c=s.charAt(num);
        return c;
    }
```